# ansible modules fail on windows with a return code of 0?

Tags: python, ansible

I am creating some simple python modules to run on windows and they are completing successfully with the status code `0`. but the output is:

```
fatal: [10.3.16.114]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 0
}
```

for example, ill create a python script to create a directory.. and it will infact create a directory and exit with a status code 0, but yet it will still show as if it failed in the output.

here is my example code:

```
#! python

import os

#print("Hello world!")

newpath = r'C:\Program Files\arbitrary' 
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)
```

Comment: ansible output with verbose logging would be helpful

Comment: I provided the exception output

Comment: just guessing here, but maybe ansible expects certain output from your module?